# How to unlock password samsung mobile s4 galaxv

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-4

I set a password in my phone model samsung S4. Now i don't need password option.I tried deactivate procedure.
i go to setting option then go to device and select lock screen then give a password then the final menu shows enable only visible Passward option only. what can i do that

Comment: Welcome to the Android Enthusiasts! It's not 100% clear what you're talking about. Have you tried switching the lock-screen type to "swipe" (or something lese but "password")?

Answer (score 1):

You will see that if the device is encrypted, in that case you will not be able to move to a PIN or to disable the password.  You first need to decrypt the device and then try disabling the password. You can find the decryption option under settings - security. Hope this helps